# Make a function loop in js whenever user clicks on an element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an array of objects that I want to display in a template. I wrote the function below and its almost working except when I click on an li, the properties of the object remain the same and don't change if I click on a different li; this is the error that I get : // uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'content') at HTMLUListElement.

Here is the code I am using :

```
function afficherDetailsPokemon() {

  const listPokemons = document.getElementById('list-pokemons');

  listPokemons.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
      const pokemonId = event.target.dataset.pokemonId;
      const pokemon = pokemons.find(p => p.id === Number(pokemonId));

      if (pokemon) {
        // Clone the template
        const template = document.getElementById('template').content.cloneNode(true);

        // Set the values of the form elements to the properties of the Pokemon object
        template.querySelector('#nom_en').value = pokemon.name.english;
        template.querySelector('#nom_fr').value = pokemon.name.french;
        template.querySelector('#attaque').value = pokemon.base.Attack;
        template.querySelector('#defense').value = pokemon.base.Defense;

        // Create a new span element for each type and append it to the type_p element
        pokemon.type.forEach(type => {
          const span = document.createElement('span');
          span.textContent = type;
          template.querySelector('#type_p').appendChild(span);
        });

        // Replace the info div with the template
        const infoDiv = document.getElementById('info');
        infoDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(template, infoDiv);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I am pretty new to js and would appreciate your help.

When I click on an li, it does display the properties of the name I select first, but when I try a second time I get the error  // uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'content') at HTMLUListElement.

If it helps, this happens on the line where I clone the template.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the code in the template, it has an inline `onclick` that's getting this error.

Comment: When you call the getElementById method querying the page from the element with an id of template, it is unable to find it and returns null. Which is where your error is coming from.

Comment: @ThisGuy [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) is always uppercase